# Cropping tool is not working while changed the file twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this plugin  https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper.
My problem is that cropping tool is not working while change the file twice.
I am using two cropper in same page but when I change first image in one modal then it's working fine, and when I change image in second modal then it's also working fine. But when I want to change first image in first modal than dragger is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use following settings:

{dragCrop:true,
multiple:true,
movable:true}